# How to type theorem with automatic number by opmac

Tags: theorems, plain-tex, number

It is quite convenient to use the opmac in Plain TeX, but I still do not know how to type a mathematical theorem with automatic number. At this stage, I am only able to type a theorem manually as:

```
\input opmac 

\label[sec1]
\sec Test 1
\proclaim Theorem 1.1. This is a test of \TeX.

\sec Test 2
Refer to Section \ref[sec1].

\bye
```

It seems that above Theorem 1.1 can not be referred by "\ref".

My question is how to type a slanted theorem with automatic number, so that I can refer it easily.

Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the awkward syntax of `\proclaim`:

```
\input opmac

\newcount\theoremcount
\def\thetheoremcount{\the\theoremcount}

\def\theorem#1\par{%
  \global\advance\theoremcount by 1
  \csname proclaim\endcsname
  Theorem \wlabel\thetheoremcount\thetheoremcount. \ignorespaces#1\par
}

\label[sec1]
\sec Test 1

\label[thm]
\theorem This is a test of \TeX.

\sec Test 2
Refer to Section \ref[sec1] and to theorem~\ref[thm].

\bye
```

[image]

The documentation of OPmac is rather scanty. If you want to link the theorem number to the section, you have to do it yourself.

```
\input opmac

\newcount\theoremcount
\def\thetheoremcount{\the\secnum.\the\theoremcount}
\def\sechook{\global\theoremcount=0 }

\def\theorem#1\par{%
  \global\advance\theoremcount by 1
  \csname proclaim\endcsname
  Theorem \wlabel\thetheoremcount\thetheoremcount. \ignorespaces#1\par
}

\label[sec1]
\sec Test 1

\label[thm]
\theorem This is a test of \TeX.

\sec Test 2
Refer to Section \ref[sec1] and to theorem~\ref[thm].

\label[thm2]
\theorem This is a test of \TeX.

Refer to theorem~\ref[thm2].

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I borrowed the code from CTUstyle macro. Five independent registers A,B,C,D,E are declared here. We reset them in each section, see `\sechook` definition below. They can be used in numbered paragraphs by macro `\numberedpar reg{Word}`. For example

```
\def\theorem {\numberedpar A{Theorem}}
\def\corollary {\numberedpar A{Corollary}}
\def\example {\numberedpar B{Example}}
\def\notice  {\numberedpar C{Notice}}
```

This example shares numbers for Theorems and Colorraly and there are indepenent numbers for Examples and Notices.

The whole example is here:

```
\input opmac 

\newcount\numA \newcount\numB \newcount\numC \newcount\numD \newcount\numE

\def\sechook#1\relax{\numA=0 \numB=0 \numC=0 \numD=0 \numE=0 
   \seccnum=0 \tnum=0 \fnum=0 \dnum=0 \relax}

\def\numberedpar#1#2{\par \global\advance\csname num#1\endcsname by1
   \noindent\wlabel{\thesecnum.\the\csname num#1\endcsname}%
   {\bf#2 \thesecnum.\the\csname num#1\endcsname.}\space} 

\def\theorem #1\par{\numberedpar A{Theorem}{\it#1}}
\def\corollary #1\par{\numberedpar A{Corollary}{\it#1}}
\def\example {\numberedpar B{Example}}
\def\notice  {\numberedpar C{Notice}}

\label[sec1]
\sec Test 1
%\proclaim Theorem 1.1. This is a test of \TeX.

\label[TheorX]
\theorem This is Theorem.

\sec Test 2
Refer to Section \ref[sec1] and to Theorem \ref[TheorX].

\bye
```